# Functions such that $xf''(x) + f'(x) > 0$

Tags: calculus, functions

I'm struggling on how to approach this question:

Find functions $f$ such that $xf''(x) + f'(x) > 0$ with $x \in \mathbb{R}^+$

Any help?

Comment: Find *all* functions $f$, or just one?

Comment: Certainly any affine function $f(x) = a x + b$ with positive slope $a$ will do.

Answer (score 3):

Consider $g(x)=xf'(x)$; then $g'(x)=f'(x)+xf''(x)$, so you want to find the function $g$ so that it's increasing and $g(0)=0$. If $g$ is *any* differentiable function with $g(0)=0$ and $g'(x)>0$ for all $x$, then define
$$
F(x)=\begin{cases}
g'(0) & \text{if $x=0$}\\[3px]
\dfrac{g(x)}{x} & \text{if $x\ne0$}
\end{cases}
$$
and
$$
f(x)=\int_{0}^x F(t)\,dt
$$
will satisfy your requests, because
$$
f'(x)=F(x)
$$
and
$$
xf'(x)=g(x)
$$
for all $x$, so $g'(x)=xf'(x)+f''(x)>0$ by assumption.

Now it's only a matter of choosing a function $g$: if $g(x)=x$, you surely have $g'(x)>0$ and $g(0)=0$, so $F(x)=1$ and $f(x)=x$. But you can also choose
$$
g_1(x)=\arctan x,\qquad g_2(x)=e^x-1,\qquad g_3(x)=x^3+3x,\qquad \dots
$$

Comment: So would f'(x) > 0 be a sufficient condition?

Comment: @Brian $f'(x)>0$ means $g(x)/x>0$ for $x\ne0$ and $g'(0)>0$.  It's not difficult to imagine a function that's negative for $x<0$, positive for $x>0$, with positive derivative at $0$, but that's not increasing.

Answer (score 1):

\begin{equation}
xf''(x)+f'(x) = \frac{d}{dx}\left(xf'(x)\right)
\end{equation}
Which wlog
\begin{equation}
\implies xf'(x)=c
\end{equation}
where $c$ is a constant. since $x \in \mathbb{R^{+}}$, we write wlog
\begin{equation}
f'(x)=\frac{c}{x}
\end{equation}
You can maybe take it from here?

Comment: @Chinny84 added a little more material.

Comment: This is wrong. We don't have $xf''(x) + f'(x) = 0$, we have $xf''(x) + f'(x) > 0$. So $xf'(x)$ isn't constant, it's _increasing_.

Comment: @Arthur good point, forgot, was rushing an answer in my lunch break.

Answer (score 0):

Solve the differential equation $(xf'(x))'=xf''(x)+f'(x)=1$ for example. You could also replace $1$ with $e^x$

Answer (score 0):

Let $p(x)$ be a strictly positive function. Its antiderivative $P(x)$ is a strictly increasing function.

Integrating twice from $0$ to $x$,
$$xf''(x)+f'(x)=p(x),$$
$$xf'(x)=0f'(0)+\int_0^x p(x)\,dx+c=P(x)-P(0),$$
$$f'(x)=\frac{P(x)-P(0)}{x},$$
$$f(x)=f(0)+\int_0^x\frac{P(x)-P(0)}xdx.$$

---

For a nontrivial example, take $P(x)=-\dfrac1{x+1}$. Then,
$$f(x)=f(0)+\int_0^x\frac{dx}{x+1}=\ln(x+1)+c.$$
Check:
$$f'(x)=\frac1{x+1},$$
$$f''(x)=-\frac1{(x+1)^2},$$
$$xf''(x)+f'(x)=\frac1{(x+1)^2}>0.$$

Answer (score -1):

The LHS is equal to

$$\frac{d}{dt}\left(tf'(t)\right)>0$$

Integrating from $0$ to $x$:

$$\int_{0}^x  \frac{d}{dt}\left(tf'(t)\right) dt=xf'(x)-0\cdot f'(0)>0$$

How $x>0$

$$f'(x)>0$$

Then any function strictly inscreasing satisfy your equation.

Comment: So, you claim if a function (such as $xf'(x)$) has positive derivative,, then the function itself is positive.

Comment: You cannot integrate or differentiate an inequality.

Comment: @GEdgar my mistake is increasing

Comment: @Arthur why not?

Comment: @rlartiga From $1>0$ can you deduce that $x>0$ for all $x$?

Comment: @rlartiga Assume we could differentiate inequalities. Then any upwardly bounded, differentiable function is decreasing (differentiate $f(x) < M$ to see why). As for integration, remember the _constant_ of integration. If you could integrate an inequality, then from $2 > 1$ you imply that $2x + c_1 > x+c_2$ for _any_ $c_1, c_2$. This gets you into trouble quickly. Therefore: No integration or differentiation of inequalities.

Comment: @egreg with the new change is now fixed?

Comment: @Arthur but you can make definite integration over an inequality or not? Could you see the change I made?

Comment: So is this wrong?